# Pandas groupby, sort datetime in columns or take the last (most recent)

Tags: python

[I have not found exact answer on that question in those "duplicates", that jezrael suggests.]

I have quite complicated dataframe. I need to group it by 3 columns and then take the most recent (by columns 'date') value in EACH group.

```
place  customer type  date        sales
LA        m      a   2018-12-1      1
LA        m      b   2018-12-1      4
LA        m      a   2018-12-4      2
LA        m      b   2018-12-4      5
LA        m      a   2018-12-3      3
LA        m      b   2018-12-3      1
LA        m      a   2018-12-7      4
LA        m      b   2018-12-7      10
LA        f      a   2018-12-1      1
LA        f      b   2018-12-1      1
LA        f      a   2018-12-4      15
LA        f      b   2018-12-4      12
LA        f      a   2018-12-3      31
LA        f      b   2018-12-3      11
LA        f      a   2018-12-7      14
LA        f      b   2018-12-7      40
NY        m      a   2018-12-1      3
NY        m      b   2018-12-1      4
NY        m      a   2018-12-4      1
NY        m      b   2018-12-4      13
NY        m      a   2018-12-3      14
NY        m      b   2018-12-3      8
NY        m      a   2018-12-7      11
NY        m      b   2018-12-7      10
```

I need to group df by place, customer and type, and then in each subgroup select most recent date and corresponding sales:

```
place  customer type  date        sales
LA        m      a   2018-12-7      4
                 b   2018-12-7      10
          f      a   2018-12-7      40
                 b   2018-12-7      14
NY        m      a   2018-12-7      11
                 b   2018-12-7      10
```

I tried

```
gr = df.groupby([df['place'], df['customer'], df['type']]).last()
```

but this gives the last row, which generally speaking is not always the most recent date (dates can be shuffled)

Comment: @jerzrael, thanks for providing link for this solution, I could come up with `df.groupby(['place'],sort=False)['sales'].max()` could you please do add how to get OP's like output, I apologies if I missed something in your link. Since didn't find it so thought to check with you once here.

Comment: I need max('date'), not max('sales').

Comment: I came up with following solution:
    idx = df.groupby([df['place'], df['customer'], df['type']])['date'].idxmax()
    df_new = df.loc[idx].
Then one can groupby df_new, if needed.